# How to Autoexpand to a Duplicate Entry in a Combobox?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Salvete!  I have an Access database (.accdb) with a combobox that will let me select records by typing into the box and pushing enter.  Now, the list to which the combobox is bound has (of necessity) duplicates.  What I want to do is to find a way to get the text of a duplicate item into the combobox.  Problem is that `AutoExpand` only seems to see the first match.

I have a list with two columns, that looks like this:

```
Bob     20
Harry   5
Mike    45
Mike    46
Mike    78
Sherry  24
```

My code gets the index of what is displayed in the combobox, and then grabs the data from the second column.

**How can I make `Autoexpand` display the second match (Mike, in this example)?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user (and the form) to distinguish between the 3 rows that say "Mike", you'll need to display both columns.  Set your combobox to display both columns.  Then, when the user types "M", the box will center on the first of the 3 rows with Mike.

One way this can be done is by changing your row source to "Select Name, Num from Tbl". Or just use the built-in wizard when making a new combobox.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I used the wizard to begin with.  The combobox already displays both columns if you show the dropdown.  It is easy for the *user* to distinguish the three, but my question is how can I get to the second "Mike" by typing?  I want to do something like this:  Type "Mike" and the first entry shows when I push enter, then push enter again to show the second entry.

Comment: Try this: Type "Mike" and alt+up/down to open the dropdown.  Then use up/down to find the entry you want.  Then press enter to select it.

Comment: Hmmm...  That is a workaround; not what I'm looking for.  Besides, it doesn't work.  alt will open the menu, but you can't arrowkey off the first match.  This needs to be a coded solution.